# Custom account page that accepts a query parameter

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, endpoints

I am trying to add a new account submenu page that takes a query parameter.

I have the following which works:

```
add_action('init', function() {
  add_rewrite_endpoint('scheduled-order-create', EP_PAGES);
});

add_action('woocommerce_account_scheduled-order-create_endpoint', function() {
  include 'scheduled-order-create.php';
});
```

Then I can see the page at `/my-account/scheduled-order-create`.

Now I want this page to accept a query parameter, but if I just navigate to `/my-account/scheduled-order-create?product=1` the page is a 404.

I've tried this for my `init` hook:

```
add_action('init', function() {
  add_rewrite_tag('%product%', '([0-9]+)');
  add_rewrite_endpoint('scheduled-orders', EP_PAGES);
  add_rewrite_endpoint("scheduled-order-create/([0-9]+)/?", 'index.php?product=$matches[1]', EP_PAGES);
});
```

But now the page is always a 404 even without the parameter.

I am refreshing the permalinks page after all changes.

Comment: Why don't you just look for the query parameter in your page template? `$_GET['param']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `add_rewrite_endpoint("scheduled-order-create/([0-9]+)/?", ...);` doesn't work because `add_rewrite_endpoint()` doesn't work with custom RegEx pattern.

And remember that in addition to default *public query vars* like `cat`, `tag`, `year` and `author`, WordPress also makes all public post types and taxonomies (with a non-empty `query_var` value when registered — see [`register_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#parameters) and [`register_taxonomy()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/#parameters)) be readable from the URL and used with the *main query*, so make sure your query string *name* does not conflict with those query vars. Otherwise, you'd end up with a `404` error because WordPress tried to query something else than what should've been queried.

Therefore, despite that `add_rewrite_endpoint('scheduled-order-create', EP_PAGES);` does work, navigating to `/my-account/scheduled-order-create?product=1` results in the `404` error because WordPress (or `WP_Query`) couldn't find a (public/published) `product` post with the *slug* `1` — `product` is a post type registered by WooCommerce with the query var defaults to the post type slug.

*So you need to use another name for the URL query string*, e.g. use `prod_id` in place of `product` as in `https://example.com/my-account/scheduled-order-create?prod_id=1`.

### Additional Notes

In WooCommerce, there's actually a filter hook you can use to easily add custom `my-account` endpoints, and I'd use that hook unless if I wanted to enable the endpoint for *all* Pages:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_query_vars', function ( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars['scheduled-order-create'] = 'scheduled-order-create';
    return $query_vars;
} );
```

However, you still *need to* flush/re-generate the permalinks (just visit the permalink settings page).

### Additional Code

Or as an alternative to using the `prod_id` query string in the URL.

- You can use path-based rewrite endpoints such as `scheduled-order-create/product`:

  ```php
  // Manually using add_rewrite_endpoint():
  add_action( 'init', function () {
      add_rewrite_endpoint( 'scheduled-order-create/product', EP_PAGES,
        'scheduled-order-create' );
  } );

  // Or using the WooCommerce's filter hook:
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_query_vars', function ( $query_vars ) {
      $query_vars['scheduled-order-create'] = 'scheduled-order-create/product';
      return $query_vars;
  } );

  // To get the product ID (e.g. 123 as in example.com/my-account/scheduled-order-create/product/123):
  $product_id = get_query_var( 'scheduled-order-create' );
  ```

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't think of the fact that `product` was already being used.